# Difficulty setting up VPN on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, vpn

I have setup VPN on a Windows Server 2003 box. I also added rules to the firewall to pass traffic through for port 1723 and IP protocol 47 (GRE).

I'm able to connect to the VPN, but then I'm not able to navigate the network. I'm able to ping the box which the VPN is setup on, but nothing else on the network.

The machine I'm connecting to the VPN on has a 192.168.x.x address and the VPN IP is on a 10.x.x.x IP range, so that isn't the problem.

There must be an issue with the way the VPN server is doing the routing but I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. Can anybody lend a helping hand?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: The VPN is setup using a single NIC for clarification purposes.

Comment: What does the routing table on the client computer look like, after connecting to the VPN? By default, the Microsoft VPN client assigns your default gateway to the remote network (the "Use default gateway on remote network" checkbox in the "Advanced" TCP/IP properties for the VPN connection). If you turn that off, instead of seeing your default gateway change you'll see an entry for the remote network with a gateway of the IP address assigned to the client's VPN adapter.

Comment: I already unchecked the box for using the default gateway on the remote network, but I tried it both with that and without. I'm pretty sure this an issue with the traffic not being routed properly, but I'm not sure how to set the routes up.

Googling around while this question is up, will let you guys know if I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to assign IPs that were on a different range than the NIC on the VPN server was using. I changed the IP block to something on the same IP range and it started working.